# Приостановка главного потока на время выполнения события

Tags: c#, многопоточность, события

Здравствуйте! Есть программа,которая работает с внешним осциллографом. Осциллограф начинает работу при наступлении события `OnDataReadyEventHandler`. Нужно приостановить основной поток и ожидать окончания события.

```
_OscDevice.OnDataReady += OnDataReadyEventHandler; // Регистрируем обработчик события о готовности данных измерений
```

Событие наступает при вызове функции Begin();

```
private void button2_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Load_Data();
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        Begin();//получение данных с осциллографа
        //Здесь нужно сделать ожидание обработки события OnDataReadyEventHandler,чтобы при следующем вызове функции Begin() не было конфликта из-за обращения к используемому объекту при следующем вызове Begin()
        ........
        Begin();
    }
```

Сам обработчик:

```
private void OnDataReadyEventHandler(uint nChannelsMask)
    {
        // !!! Не отображайте результаты на форме в данной функции - это будет приводить к ошибкам.
        // !!! Отображайте результаты в ф-ции ProcessData().

        SafeProcessData(nChannelsMask);    
    }

    private void SafeProcessData(uint nChannelsMask)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(new InvokeDelegateForProcessData(ProcessData), new Object[] { nChannelsMask });
        else
            ProcessData(nChannelsMask);
    }
```

Comment: Что-то вы делаете не так. Основной поток _нельзя_ останавливать. Расскажите лучше, чего вы хотите добиться на самом деле.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, если остановить основной поток и ожидание до наступления события OnDataReady будет долгим, то окно будет заметно подвисать? Может стоит изменить логику работы программы?

Comment: задача: провести ряд измерений с помощью осциллографа.
обмен командами осуществляется через ком-порт. протокол такой: на измеритель посылается команда начала изменения 0xFF, через некоторое время на комп приходит сигнал годности или брака, 'g' или 'b'. А при многократном измерении for(...) {Begin()} на измеритель шлются несколько 0xFF подряд, не дожидаясь результата измерения

Comment: Поэтому у меня подозрение, что ком-порт не дожидается результата осциллографа, а результат осциллографа формируется в событии

Comment: По сути, нужно синхронизировать работы ком-порта с осциллографа

Comment: если функцию Begin вызывать по нажатию клавиши, то многократные нажатия срабатывают корректно. А если вызывать в цикле, проходит только первое измерение.

Comment: Окей. А зачем тут блокировка главного потока всё же?

Comment: Работа с устройствами вообще должна быть вынесена из главного потока.

Comment: ну точнее не блокировка, а ожидание готовности устройства

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Останавливать главной поток нельзя. Но, как я понимаю, вам это и не требуется - вам же надо просто дождаться окончания асинхронной операции, прежде чем продолжать работу?

Именно для таких случаев и придумано асинхронной программирование. Пусть функция `Begin` возвращает задачу, которая перейдет в завершенное состояние после получения события.

Тогда ваш обработчик будет выглядеть вот так:

```
private async void button2_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Load_Data();
    await Task.Delay(250);
    await Begin();//получение данных с осциллографа
    ........
    await Begin();
}
```

Теперь осталось две вещи. Первая - вернуть задачу из функции `Begin`. Это делается как-то так:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs;
private Task Begin() {
    if (tcs != null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Операция уже выполняется");
    var tcs_local = tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    // Тут остается старый код этой функции

    return tcs_local.Task; // Важно использовать именно локальную переменную - потому что к этому моменту tcs может оказаться уже снова null.
}

private void OnDataReadyEventHandler(uint nChannelsMask)
{
    SafeProcessData(nChannelsMask);
    if (tcs != null)
    {
        var tcs_local = tcs;
        tcs = null;
        tcs_local.SetResult(null); // Главный поток сразу после этой строчки может начать новую операцию - поэтому важно установить tcs в null заранее      
    }
}
```

Заодно мы совершенно бесплатно получили проверку времени выполнения на одновременное выполнение операций.

Вторая вещь - надо как-то заблокировать нажатие на кнопку во время выполнения операции - поскольку мы все сделали настолько хорошо, что пользователь теперь может в процессе обработки нажатия на кнопку нажать ее еще раз.

Ну и третье замечание. В коде выше я предполагал, что событие `OnDataReadyEventHandler` может произойти только тогда, когда мы его ждем. Если же осциллограф может выкинуть его в любой момент - то следует озаботиться атомарным доступом к переменной `tcs`. К счастью, здесь достаточно всего лишь операции `Interlocked.CompareExchange` в методе `Begin` - и `Interlocked.Exchange` в обработчике события.

Comment: Ой, обознался. Там дважды `Begin`, а не `Begin`/`End`.

Comment: @VlaD Спасибо, без вас бы долго допирал. Правда, между действиями пришлось await Task.Delay()  поставить.

По поводу повторного нажатия: button1. Enabled = false; ... button1. Enabled = true; не прокатывает:(

По третьему замечанию: событие OnDataReadyEventHandler происходит только тогда, когда мы этого ждем. В методе Begin() вызывается функция Osc. Run = 1, которая запускает осциллограф и вызывает событие.

Comment: @Shach: ваш комментарий скорее всего адресован автору ответа

Comment: @PavelMayorov: комментарий, судя по всему, для вас.

Comment: @Shach, у меня там неспроста многоточие стоит - что нужно по логике работы с устройством, то и надо ставить. По поводу *"непрокатывающего"* `button1. Enabled = false` - а ничего, что обработчик называется `button2_Click_3`? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ничего, сочтите это за псевдокод)

Comment: В случае сферического псевдокода в вакууме `button1.Enabled = false` должно сработать.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае нужны объекты синхронизации, можно сделать так.

```
// создаём объект синхронизации не взведённым
AutoResetEvent sync = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void button2_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Load_Data();
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    Begin();//получение данных с осциллографа
    // ждём когда его установят в true
    sync.WaitOne();
    ........
    Begin();
}
private void OnDataReadyEventHandler(uint nChannelsMask)
{
    SafeProcessData(nChannelsMask);
    // устанавливаем 
    sync.Set();
}
```

Comment: при добавлении sync.WaitOne() отладчик не доходит до  sync.Set() в событии. При комментировании sync.WaitOne() доходит.